# Particle masses

Tags: particle-physics, mass, standard-model

if there is no theory to predict/calcukate the masses of the fundamental particles, where do they get the values for the quarks, as quoted in the standard model?

And since the composite particles get most of their mass from the binding energy and not from the constituent quarks, couldn't it be that the masses of the quarks are over estimated and the binding energies underestimated, or vise versa?

Answer (score 0):

I believe the quark masses are obtained from lattice Quantum Chromodynamics (QCD) calculations on a giant computer. In essence, they use the quark masses as free parameters and calculate hadron masses. The adopted masses are those that give the best fit. See [this link](http://news.sciencemag.org/physics/2010/04/mass-common-quark-finally-nailed-down) for details.